# how to fetch url domain from HtmlDocument?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack`

how can I get the domain from the following objects?

```
  private Url mUrl { get; set; }

  private HtmlDocument currentHtmlDocument { get; set; }
```

I mean the domain to which I should concatenate the

relative path of the js and css that appear in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `Url` is a `Uri`, so you can use its [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) property.

As to the `HtmlDocument`, you should be able to get to the `Uri` via the [DocumentUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmldocument.documenturi%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property. Then just use its `Host` property